# Wild Card Feature on the Field Name in Lucene

Tags: lucene

I have a json data which is flatten for the Lucene Document. This json contains array also with each element having an identifier. For Ex :

```
{
 "data":[
    {
      "id" : 01,
      "name" : "Test1",
      "category":[
         { 
           "id" : "100,
           "type" : "AX1,
         },
         { 
           "id" : "101,
           "type" : "AX2,
         }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id" : 02,
      "name" : "Test1",
      "category":[
         { 
           "id" : "102,
           "type" : "AX1,
         },
         { 
           "id" : "103,
           "type" : "AX3,
         }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The flatten lucene document is :

```
-- Document -- : 
  Field : data.id                , Value : 01
  Field : data.id.01.name        , Value : Test1
  Field : data.id.01.category.id          , Value : 100
  Field : data.id.01.category.id.100.type , Value : AX1
  Field : data.id.01.category.id          , Value : 101
  Field : data.id.01.category.id.101.type , Value : AX2
```

similarly for other entries of the above json data

How can I achieve the objective to have lucene query which can search for all category where type is : AX1 and also to get the id of the matching entry ?

I thought if I write the lucene query in the wild card format i.e.
+(data.id. * .category.id. * .type : AX1)  this can search on any matching doc.
However it doesn't work as probably lucene may not have wild card feature on field name ?

Comment: Why Lucene? It does not seem to be the right tool for the job (based on the very limited information in your question).